# How to hide rows while editing a specific row from the user in gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, events, gridview, edit

I have a web application which is connected to SQL server management studio.
I have one problem to finish my application. 
In my gridview users are able to edit their own reservation, but once i reach update part for the gridview it shows me that the users are able to edit the other reservation and here are some images to show you the meaning of this:

1) this the code in my gridview events

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((row.Cells[9].Text.Trim()).Equals(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) == false)
        {
            //row.BackColor = Color.Red;
            row.Cells[0].Controls.Clear();          
        }        
   }
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Changed";

    GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        int currentIndex = row.RowIndex;

        if (currentIndex != e.NewEditIndex)
        {
            row.Visible = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

2) this is to show you that user can edit only their own reservation

[image]

so how can i solve this ?

Comment: 3) this is to show you while the user updating his reservation, he will be able to edit other reservation.

http://store1.up-00.com/2015-04/142868080993.png

Comment: Kindly consider instead pasting your code snippets in the question to speed up responses.

Comment: I got your question. Can you please paste your whole code in your question?

Comment: can you please check my question again .. I have added my code over there

Answer (score 0):

I have updated GridView's `RowEditing` event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
     GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
     // Bind Grid Again Here
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question, but what do you mean by put bind grid again here ? I'm not really expert to know about bind grid code